# Select and remove/delete multiple rows simultaneously in swift UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I have an application with two table views each displaying data from one entity based on an attribute (frequent) with data type Bool. So if 'frequent' is true, that item is displayed in view1 and if 'frequent' is false, then that item is displayed in view2.

when a user checks a row, the data along with the row number will be held in a temporary array (checked), (to allow the user the option of unchecking/unselecting a row).

Then when 'Done' is clicked, the attribute (frequent) will be toggled for the contents in the selected rows (checked); which the function to populate those views will take care of actually moving the data.

Currently, the checking/unchecking, moving the data is working fine. But the current view does not update the table view by removing the rows that are moved. I have to go to another view and comeback for the table to reload the data and reflect the current data content.

I tried to include tableView.reloadData(); self.tableView.reloadData() at the end of the @IBAction for the 'Done' button but I still can not solve this issue.

I tried to hold the indexPath of the selected rows in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' and use that array in the @IBAction to pass it to 'tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths' one by one or as array but I get the error

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var mySelectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        if mySelectedCell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
            mySelectedCell.accessoryType = .None
            selectedRow[indexPath.row] = false
            //remove content of 'indexPath.row' from 'checked'
            itemIndex = indexOfItemInChecked(myItemFav[indexPath.row] as! Item)
            itemIndexPath = indexOfIndexPath(indexPath)
            selectedRowIndexPath.removeAtIndex(itemIndexPath)
            checked.removeAtIndex(itemIndex)
        } else {
            mySelectedCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            checked.append(myItemFav[indexPath.row] as! Item)
            selectedRow[indexPath.row] = true
//Array to hold indexPath of selected rows              selectedRowIndexPath.append(tblFavorites.indexPathForCell(mySelectedCell)!)
        }
    }
```

And the function for the 'Done' button is

```
    @IBAction func btnDone(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let itemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        if !selectedRow.isEmpty {
            for key in selectedRow.keys {
                if selectedRow[key] == true {
                    checkedIndex.append(key)
                }
            }
        }
        checkedIndex.sort(>)
        //println(checkedIndex)
        for key in checkedIndex {
            myItemFav[key].setValue(true as Bool, forKey: "purchased")
        }
//this for loop code, when included gives me the error below
            for path in selectedRowIndexPath {
            tblFavorites.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        context.save(nil)
    }
```

terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

if I remove that for loop, it all works except updating the tableview until I change view and come back to it.

HELP!

Comment: Before calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` you need to make sure that the table view data source will return a matching count of rows.  Basically, you had 7 rows and deleted one but `numberOfRowsInSection` said there were still 7.

Comment: what are you returning for `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` ?

Comment: I'm returning 1 for tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

And @philip, that's the problem I'm trying to solve. My data source is myItemFav which is the data from the table with attribute 'frequent' true. The IBAction just changes that attribute for the content of the checked rows to false. I just don't understand why/how the table view doesn't update the number of rows.